# how do I get to files save on my windows system

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, files

I've installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. How do I get access to my Windows files with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Open Nautilus. After I installed Ubuntu it automatically added my Windows partition to the side bar as shown here:

[image]

Your files are probably in the Documents and Settings directory or otherwise can be found under Users.
And you can copy/paste files from and to this partition.